# Sample application of Hyperledger Fabric Node SDK

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

If somebody has link of sample-app/sample-web-app of Hyperledger Fabric Node SDK, please post it. It is said in [official document](https://web.archive.org/web/20170416200942/http://fabric-sdk-node.readthedocs.io:80/en/master/sample-web-app/) that they have sample-app [here](http://https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/examples/sdk/node/app.js) and sample-web-app [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/examples/sdk/node/web-app.js) but the urls are empty

Answer (score 2):

There are few examples on [fabric-sample](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples) repository in particular you probably would like to consider taking look on balance transfer example [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/release/balance-transfer). Which provides decent example of application developed based on NodeJS SDK and covers major parts.

Comment: In the balance transfer sample, the `network-config-aws.json` in the apps directory reads the admin keys, certificates and the ca certificates locally. Does that mean these have to be copied at the client node manually, if I want to setup the SDK for a client?

Comment: not sure what do you mean, since this is an SDK client example.

Comment: yes, so the scenario is, I want to setup a client which would interact with the fabric network. This client is a separate node. Here, in balance transfer, [link] (https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release/balance-transfer/app/network-config-aws.json), what are the `tlscacerts` and the `admin.key` and `admin.certs` and how should they be generated for the client?

Comment: communication within HLF is mutual TLS, hence you need TLS certificats, admin.key and admin.certs are private key and certificate used by client, which has admin role.

Comment: Oh..ok. so I should register the client as an "user" who also has admin certs.